# How do you filter table via JavaScript with a bootstrap dropdown?

Tags: javascript, filter, html-table, bootstrap-4

I think my question is a little bit more complicated than what I saw on the internet because I need to make multiple filtrations on a single table. So here's my code:

```js
function searchTable() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
  input = document.getElementById("search");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("table");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
      if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

#table th,
#table td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 12px;
}

#table tr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

#table tr.header,
#table tr:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="input-group">
  <input class="form-control" id="search" onkeyup="searchTable();" placeholder="search distribution" name="s" autocomplete="off" autofocus>
  <div class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Devices</button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="">Desktop</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0)">Mobile</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0)">Tablet</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<table id="table" class="table-striped table-hover">
  <tr class="header">
    <th style="width:35%;">Distribution</th>
    <th style="width:35%;">Supported devices</th>
    <th style="width:20%;">Download</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Glass '17</td>
    <td>Desktop & Mobile</td>
    <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" target="_blank">Download</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Glass '17</td>
    <td>Tablet</td>
    <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" target="_blank">Download</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Other distribution</td>
    <td>Mobile</td>
    <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" target="_blank">Download</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Distribution 3</td>
    <td>Tablet & Mobile</td>
    <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" target="_blank">Download</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The `seachTable()` function is for filtering the table by the content of `<td>` (first child). What I am trying to achieve is also filtering the table by device type. The hard part is that some distributions are supported on more than 1 device type.

---

### What I tried?

```js
function searchTable() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;

  var input = document.getElementById("search");
  var filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  var table = document.getElementById("table");
  var tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

  for (var i = 1; i < tr.length; i++) {
    var tds = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
    var firstCol = tds[0].textContent.toUpperCase();
    var secondCol = tds[1].textContent.toUpperCase();
    if (firstCol.indexOf(filter) > -1 || secondCol.indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      tr[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      tr[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}

function searchTableDevice(device) {
  var filter, table, tr, td, i;

  $("#deviceSelector").html(device);

  var filter = device.toUpperCase();
  var table = document.getElementById("table");
  var tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  if (device == "all") {
    $("#table tr").css("display", "");
    $("#deviceSelector").html("Devices");
  } else {
    searchTable();
    for (var i = 1; i < tr.length; i++) {
      var tds = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
      var secondCol = tds[1].textContent.toUpperCase();
      if (secondCol.indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

#table th,
#table td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 12px;
}

#table tr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

#table tr.header,
#table tr:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="input-group">
  <input class="form-control" id="search" onkeyup="searchTable();" placeholder="search distribution" name="s" autocomplete="off" autofocus>
  <div class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" id="deviceSelector">
        Devices
      </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="searchTableDevice(this.innerHTML)">Desktop</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="searchTableDevice(this.innerHTML)">Mobile</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="searchTableDevice(this.innerHTML)">Tablet</a>
      <div role="separator" class="dropdown-divider"></div>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="searchTableDevice('all')">All</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<table id="table" class="table-striped table-hover">
  <tr class="header">
    <th style="width:35%;">Distribution</th>
    <th style="width:35%;">Supported devices</th>
    <th style="width:20%;">Download</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Glass '17</td>
    <td>Desktop & Mobile</td>
    <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" target="_blank">Download</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Glass '17</td>
    <td>Tablet</td>
    <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" target="_blank">Download</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Other distribution</td>
    <td>Mobile</td>
    <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" target="_blank">Download</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Distribution 3</td>
    <td>Tablet & Mobile</td>
    <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" target="_blank">Download</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I tried making a new function `searchTableDevice()` with similar content as `searchTable()`, but instead of getting the text from an input it is getting the text from the `<a>` elements in the drop-down. What happened? `searchTable()` is setting `style.display = "block"` to the rows that match the text from the input and the hidden by `seacrhTableDevice()` rows were also displayed. I totally got confused about what to do.

---

Any help would be highly appreciated and welcomed. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working code.

```js
$(function () {
 $('#search').on('input', function () {
  searchRow();
 });
})

function searchRow() {
 var $rows = $('#table > tbody > tr').not(".header");
 var val1 = $.trim($('#search').val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
 var val2 = $.trim($("#deviceSelector").text()).toLowerCase();
 val2 = (val2 === "devices") ? "" : val2;

 $rows.show().filter(function () {
  var text1 = $(this).find('td:nth-child(1)').text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
  var text2 = $(this).find('td:nth-child(2)').text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
  return !~text1.indexOf(val1) || !~text2.indexOf(val2);
 }).hide();
}

function searchTableDevice(device) {
 var filter, table, tr, td, i;

 $("#deviceSelector").html(device);

 if (device == "all") {
  $("#deviceSelector").html("Devices");
 }

 searchRow();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<style type="text/css">
 #table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-top: 20px;
 }

 #table th,
 #table td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 12px;
 }

 #table tr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
 }

 #table tr.header,
 #table tr:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
 }
</style>

<div class="input-group">
 <input class="form-control" id="search" placeholder="search distribution" name="s" autocomplete="off"
  autofocus>
 <div class="input-group-btn">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"
   id="deviceSelector">
       Devices
     </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
   <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="searchTableDevice(this.innerHTML)">Desktop</a>
   <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="searchTableDevice(this.innerHTML)">Mobile</a>
   <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="searchTableDevice(this.innerHTML)">Tablet</a>
   <div role="separator" class="dropdown-divider"></div>
   <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="searchTableDevice('all')">All</a>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

<table id="table" class="table-striped table-hover">
 <tr class="header">
  <th style="width:35%;">Distribution</th>
  <th style="width:35%;">Supported devices</th>
  <th style="width:20%;">Download</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Glass '17</td>
  <td>Desktop & Mobile</td>
  <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" target="_blank">Download</a></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Glass '17</td>
  <td>Tablet</td>
  <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" target="_blank">Download</a></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Other distribution</td>
  <td>Mobile</td>
  <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" target="_blank">Download</a></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Distribution 3</td>
  <td>Tablet & Mobile</td>
  <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" target="_blank">Download</a></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: not really, I wanted to filter the table to display only the rows that have "mobile" in their second cell, if in the dropdown the user clicks on "mobile"

Comment: thanks for the feedback. I fixed it and updated the code

Comment: Yes, but if you select for example "Desktop", it will list all distributions for desktop. And then if in the input search you type something then it also lists distributions for other devices. I want to make it list only the distributions for the selected device until the user selects "all". I worked some more on my code and I will update it with the new version within the next 2 minutes.

Comment: Thanks for your time in answering my question. If you think what I want is not possible please let me know and I will just remove the device selector from my website

Comment: "_Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined_" for line 1 "_$(function () {_"
I am sure jQuery is running.

 The dropdown filtering is working, the rest is not.

Comment: I managed to fix it. I just added this attribute _onkeyup="searchRow()"_ to the `input`

Comment: @MonaLisa  Updated the entire code above. Please verify.

Comment: Nope. "$" is still not defined. I am okay using _onkeyup_ on the input

Comment: The issue is with the jQuery library reference. Now I corrected it. You can find the working example above.

Comment: I am not using the CDN and I have downloaded jQuery 3.2.1. And again - I am okay using the onkeyup attribute - users do not have access to my code, scripts and etc